# How to find the invalid date records in Vertica DB?

Tags: vertica

Vertica DB has a column called `created_ts`, which has records like 3/15/2016, 03/15/2016, 2016/03/15 and 15/03/2016. And I want to filter the records which does not follow the DD/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: Could you show us your current query?

Comment: I have the query for Teradata DB. which has SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR table so that i can join that table and got the output. Below is my query                                                                                        sel count(*)-(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM DP_VEDW_NGN.STG_SITE_CATALYST A
LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR
on  (CALENDAR_DATE (FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') (CHAR(10))) = A.date_time 
AND A.date_time  IS NOT NULL) as Invalid_Date,'date_time' AS COLUMN_NAME
from  DP_VEDW_NGN.STG_SITE_CATALYST

Answer (score 0):

This should identify most strings that are not valid DD/MM/YYYY dates, though you'd have to add a little more complexity if you want to weed out such invalid dates as April 31 (or Feb 29 on non-leap-years).

```
select * from my_table
where not (translate(created_ts,'0123456789','9999999999')='99/99/9999' 
           and split_part(created_ts,'/',1) between '01' and '31' 
           and split_part(created_ts,'/',2) between '01' and '12')
```

Comment: The query not allowing me to translate because created_ts has timestamp in it.The 'split_part(created_ts,'/',2) between '01' and '12')'  which is not return any value . but the same line working for 'split_part(created_ts,'/',2) between '01' and '31')'. unfortunately i do not have any invalid month records.

Comment: I modified the query like `select * from
(SELECT DATE_PART('month' ,created_ts)||'/'||DATE_PART('day' ,created_ts)||'/'||DATE_PART('year' ,created_ts) as created_ts
from ROYALTY_STG.STG_DL_FILES ) A
where Not(split_part(created_ts,'/',1) between '01' and '12' 
and split_part(created_ts,'/',2) between '01' and '31'
and split_part(created_ts,'/',3) between '2000' and '9999')` . The month part is not fetching any records between 01 and 12.